# select max(id) from joined table inefficient query plan

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, query-performance, postgresql-10

I have a view **req_res** which joins 2 tables - Request and Response inner joined on requestId. Request has primary key - ID column.

When I query (**Query 1**):

```
select max(ID) from req_res where ID > 1000000 and ID < 2000000;
```

Explain plan: **hash join**: Index scan of Request.ID and seqential scan of Response.request_id

query duration: **30s**

When I lower the boundaries to 900k (**Query 2**):

```
select max(ID) from req_res where ID > 1000000 and ID < 1900000;
```

Plan: **nested loop**: Index scan of Request.ID and Index only scan of Response.request_id

query duration: **3s**

When I play with first query and disable hash join - `set enable_hashjoin=off;` I get Merge join plan. When I disable also the merge join plan with `set enable_mergejoin=off;` I get nested loop, which completes in **3 seconds (instead of 30 using hash join)**.

Size of the Request table is ~70 Mil records. Most of the requests have response counterpart, but some of them don't.

Version: PostgreSQL 10.10

req_res DDL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.req_res
AS SELECT req.id,
    res.req_id,
    res.body::character varying(500),
    res.time,
    res.duration,
    res.balance,
    res.header::character varying(100),
    res.created_at
   FROM response res
     JOIN request req ON req.req_id = res.req_id;
```

Query 1 Plan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=2834115.70..2834115.71 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=154709.729..154709.730 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=467727 read=685320 dirtied=214, temp read=240773 written=239751
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2493060.64..2831172.33 rows=1177346 width=8) (actual time=143800.101..154147.080 rows=1198706 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (req.req_id = res.req_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=467727 read=685320 dirtied=214, temp read=240773 written=239751
        ->  Append  (cost=0.44..55619.59 rows=1177346 width=16) (actual time=0.957..2354.648 rows=1200001 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=438960 read=32014
              ->  Index Scan using "5_5_req_pkey" on _hyper_2_5_chunk rs  (cost=0.44..19000.10 rows=399803 width=16) (actual time=0.956..546.231 rows=399999 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((id >= 49600001) AND (id <= 50800001))
                    Buffers: shared hit=178872 read=10742
              ->  Index Scan using "7_7_req_pkey" on _hyper_2_7_chunk rs_1  (cost=0.44..36619.50 rows=777543 width=16) (actual time=0.037..767.744 rows=800002 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((id >= 49600001) AND (id <= 50800001))
                    Buffers: shared hit=260088 read=21272
        ->  Hash  (cost=1367864.98..1367864.98 rows=68583298 width=8) (actual time=143681.850..143681.850 rows=68568554 loops=1)
              Buckets: 262144  Batches: 512  Memory Usage: 7278kB
              Buffers: shared hit=28764 read=653306 dirtied=214, temp written=233652
              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1367864.98 rows=68583298 width=8) (actual time=0.311..99590.021 rows=68568554 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=28764 read=653306 dirtied=214
                    ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_2_chunk wt  (cost=0.00..493704.44 rows=24941244 width=8) (actual time=0.309..14484.420 rows=24950147 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=661 read=243631
                    ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_6_chunk wt_1  (cost=0.00..503935.04 rows=24978804 width=8) (actual time=0.334..14487.931 rows=24963020 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=168 read=253979
                    ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_8_chunk wt_2  (cost=0.00..370225.50 rows=18663250 width=8) (actual time=0.327..10837.291 rows=18655387 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=27935 read=155696 dirtied=214
Planning time: 3.986 ms
Execution time: 154709.859 ms
```

Query 2 Plan:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2634042.50..2634042.51 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5525.626..5525.627 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=8764620 read=12779
  ->  Gather  (cost=2634042.29..2634042.50 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=5525.609..5525.705 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=8764620 read=12779
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2633042.29..2633042.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5515.507..5515.508 rows=1 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=8764620 read=12779
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.88..2632023.83 rows=407382 width=8) (actual time=5.383..5261.979 rows=332978 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=8764620 read=12779
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.44..40514.98 rows=407383 width=16) (actual time=0.035..924.498 rows=333334 loops=3)
                          Buffers: shared hit=446706
                          ->  Parallel Index Scan using "5_5_req_pkey" on _hyper_2_5_chunk rs  (cost=0.44..16667.91 rows=166585 width=16) (actual time=0.033..169.854 rows=133333 loops=3)
                                Index Cond: ((id >= 49600001) AND (id <= 50600001))
                                Buffers: shared hit=190175
                          ->  Parallel Index Scan using "7_7_req_pkey" on _hyper_2_7_chunk rs_1  (cost=0.44..23847.07 rows=240798 width=16) (actual time=0.039..336.091 rows=200001 loops=3)
                                Index Cond: ((id >= 49600001) AND (id <= 50600001))
                                Buffers: shared hit=256531
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.44..6.33 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1000001)
                          Buffers: shared hit=8317914 read=12779
                          ->  Index Only Scan using "2_2_response_pkey" on _hyper_3_2_chunk wt  (cost=0.44..2.11 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1000001)
                                Index Cond: (req_id = req.req_id)
                                Heap Fetches: 0
                                Buffers: shared hit=3000005
                          ->  Index Only Scan using "6_6_response_pkey" on _hyper_3_6_chunk wt_1  (cost=0.44..2.11 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1000001)
                                Index Cond: (req_id = req.req_id)
                                Heap Fetches: 192906
                                Buffers: shared hit=3551440 read=7082
                          ->  Index Only Scan using "8_8_response_pkey" on _hyper_3_8_chunk wt_2  (cost=0.44..2.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=443006)
                                Index Cond: (req_id = req.req_id)
                                Heap Fetches: 162913
                                Buffers: shared hit=1766469 read=5697
Planning time: 0.839 ms
Execution time: 5525.814 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain!) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the formatting and indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Showing us the view's query would also help.

Comment: How many of your requests do not have responses?

Comment: only 716 requests doesn't have responses

Comment: Two observations: you compare a parallel plan to sequential plan, in addition most of the i/o's are already cached in the second case. Are these results repeatable? or is it caused by running query plan 2 after the first one? Do you have current statistics on the tables?

Comment: The results are repeatable, we typically do several queries like this and we managed to hit CPU IO wait above 90% and make DB very unstable. When I lowered the ID boundary below 1Mil records or turned off hash joins the problem disappears. Which stats do you want to see ?